# Retrieving data in a map

Tags: java, sql, object, collections, hashmap

```
public class Dashboard {
int REQUEST_ID, PRICE, Status;           
String LOGIN_USER;

public int getREQUEST_ID() {
 return REQUEST_ID;
 }

 public void setREQUEST_ID(int rEQUEST_ID) {
  REQUEST_ID = rEQUEST_ID;
 }

  //all getters and setters
  public class MapKey {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

   public MapKey(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override Hashcode and equals
public class DBConnection {
 public ArrayList<Dashboard>  getStoreResult() {
   ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec;

 try{
  Class.forName("");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("");

  HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapStatus = new HashMap<>();
  while (rs.next()) {
    Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
    MapKey key = new MapKey(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        dashRec= new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        map.put(key, dashRec);
    }
    Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
    dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
    dash.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
    dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
    dash.setStatus(rs.getInt(4));/////STATUS
    map.get(id).add(dash);
    if (!mapStatus.containsKey(id) || mapStatus.get(id)>dash.getPROCESSED()){
                mapStatus.put(id, dash.getPROCESSED());
            } 
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

I want to create a new Hashmap with key as req_id+name+lowest status no of a specific set.Here set refers to number of rows of a particular ReqId. For e.g.:For reqid 123,we have 7rows constituting as a set. The lowest status no is 1.So value key would be 123 A 1.Similarly, for key 456,I need value 456 B 2.So for sample data hashmap must contain 3 keys with 3 values. I want this for n number of Reqid.The value for each key is arraylist which consists of rows of a specific id as objects.The value is defined in the code.

I just want change in the key of the map.

[image: SQL DB]

Comment: req 123 with name A has 2 occurrances of status 1. How to you differntiate which one to use?

Comment: It can be endless.I just need a lowest one.So we need to check each occurrence of status no.We compare each of them and get lowest out of it.

Comment: It's not like a specific one to use. I just need the lowest no..i.e for 123 reqid,it is 1.

Comment: Using “lowest status” as part of the key makes no sense. “Lowest” of what? Perhaps, you want to have req_id and name as key, but keep only those values having their status equal to the lowest status of all values with the same req_id and name? Or do you want to have just “status” as part of the key?

Comment: See I want key as reqid,name and lowest status no from the set.Here set refers to number of rows of a particular ReqId. For e.g.:For reqid 123,we have 7rows constituting as a set. The lowest status no is 1.So key would be 123+A+1.And value would be arraylist which contains all rows of a set as objects .

Comment: MapKey [reqid=123, name=A,status=1]:[Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, PRICE=5,STATUS=2],Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, PRICE=10,STATUS=3],...,..]         This is for first set.i.e for reqid 123

Comment: `lowest status` as map key along with req_id and name something weird requirement. It's better to describe how you are want to use the data. Maybe what you want is different than you describe.

Comment: @Eklavya so the requirement is like I need to pull this data on dashboard .And reqid,name are unique for each login user.There are other attributes too but for demo purpose I have showed a part of it.The status no is basically 1-Not completed,2-Partially completed,3-Completed. Completion in terms of processing. So i need to show up lowest status no along with name,reqid to give a idea whether in which lowest state data is of a particuler user is.

Comment: There is a difference between “show the lowest status” and having the lowest status as part of the key. What should happen to the `Dashboard` instances with a different status value?

Comment: @Holger I don't want to show the lowest status for now. I just want it in my key.

Comment: @Holger With different status value, we need to check with previous status no. Is it lower than that or not and then update the status variable for suppose. When we have transverse the complete set,we have lowest status no. This can now be inserted as part of key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map first outside loop

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mapStatus = new HashMap<>();
```

And in loop check and update map for new id set or existing status in larger

```
while (rs.next()) {
    ... // your existing codes
    if (!mapStatus.containsKey(id) || mapStatus.get(id)>dash.getStatus()) {
        mapStatus.put(id, dash.getStatus());
    } 
}
```

Comment: I call setstatus function defined in dashboard class.The  rs.getInt(4) is passed into it.Then I add that status into already existing map.So this if condition be checked after I add dash object into the map ?

Comment: Updated . Just add if condition after add dash object into the map. And create `mapStatus` outside loop

Comment: It does not matter whether you put this `if` before or after adding the `dash` object to map, as long as you put it after `dash.setStatus`. Or else you can actually store the `rs.getInt(4)` in the `status` variable and use it for `dash.setStatus(status)` and this `if`.

Comment: @VSSCHAITANYAChavali I got it bro.

Comment: @Eklavya I have a small requirement. There is a change in the code.Actually I want is KEY to have reqid and name of the set too. For e.g.:For reqid 123,we have 7rows constituting as a set. The lowest status no is 1 which I need as value.So key must have reqid, name and lowest status no.I need all the three name,id and lowest status no as one key and value is no of rows of the set as objects in arraylist. So can you make some changes in the given code to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Create `Map<Integer, Dashboard>` then and put `dashboard` in map instead status like  `mapStatus.put(id, dash)`

Comment: Can you plz update the code and show me?I am actually newbie to Java and will be grateful to you if you help out.

Comment: I want key as object and value as arraylist

Comment: The statement `if (!mapStatus.containsKey(id) || mapStatus.get(id)>dash.getStatus()) {
        mapStatus.put(id, dash.getStatus());
    }` can be simplified to the single statement `mapStatus.merge(id, dash.getStatus(), Math::min);` Similarly, for the other map (the updated question), you can use `map.computeIfAbsent(key, xKey -> new ArrayList<>()).add(dash);`, to put a new `ArrayList` only when necessary and add the new element to the list.

Comment: @Holger can you write a separate answer related to what you said as a code to give me proper idea? It will be quite helpful to me.

Comment: Clear your question key=`req_id+name+status`, value =`list of all set with same req_id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your main loop boils down to

```
HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapStatus = new HashMap<>();
while(rs.next()) {
    Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
    String user = rs.getString(2);
    Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
    dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
    dash.setLOGIN_USER(user);
    dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
    dash.setStatus(rs.getInt(4));
    map.computeIfAbsent(new MapKey(id, user), xKey -> new ArrayList<>()).add(dash);
    mapStatus.merge(id, dash.getPROCESSED(), Math::min);
}
```

`computeIfAbsent` will return an existing value or use the function to calculate a value to store it in the map and return. In either case, you can simply apply `add` to the returned list.

`merge` will just put the specified value into the map if no value exists, otherwise it will use the specified function to calculate a value from the old and new value. Since `Math.min(…,…)` will simply return the smaller of the two values, this will be the value to be stored or kept in the map.

Note that in your question’s code, the key was used inconsistently. You used `map.put(key, dashRec);` to store a new list when necessary, but `map.get(id).add(dash);` to retrieve the list and add to it. With the `computeIfAbsent` method, it’s impossible to be inconsistent regarding the key. Further, the `dashRec` variable became obsolete.

By the way, when `MapKey` does not carry additional semantics, there are alternative types already capable of fulfilling the purpose. E.g. you could use `Array.asList(id, user)` or, when you use Java 9+ and can preclude `null` values, `List.of(id, user)`. Or `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(id, user)`. All of these types implement appropriate `equals`/`hashCode` methods.

`Array.asList(…)` has the advantage of being expandable to more components, `SimpleImmutableEntry` provides an efficient storage for exactly two components. Java 9’s `List.of(…)` approach combines both, it allows more components but returns optimized implementations for small numbers. But it forbids `null` elements.

Comment: I want output something like this:

Comment: MapKey [reqid=123, name=A,status=1]:[Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, PRICE=5,STATUS=2],Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, PRICE=10,STATUS=3],...,..]
                    MapKey [reqid=456, name=B,status=2]:[Dashboard [reqid=456, NAME=B, PRICE=20,STATUS=3],Dashboard [reqid=456, NAME=B, PRICE=25,STATUS=2],...,..]
FOR N ROWS SAME OUTPUT

Comment: I want a single map.Kindly refer question as I have updated.